# "Cacahuate" y "cacahuete": ¿por qué varían?

Tags: etimología, historia, deletreo, préstamo-lingüístico, náhuatl

Al parecer la misma planta lleva los dos nombres casi iguales, los dos del nahuatl. Tengo entendido que "cacahuate" se usa en México y "cacahuete" en España.

¿Qué ortografía es más fiel al original? ¿Cómo pasó que se confundió la vocal?

Comment: Mani viene del quechua y se usa predominantemente en Sudamérica.

Answer (score 6):

Efectivamente, según el diccionario de americanismos la voz *[cacahuate](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cacahuate)* se usa en México, Honduras y Nicaragua, mientras que la voz *cacahuete* sería de uso en otras partes del mundo hispanohablante (en las que no se prefiera la voz *[maní](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=man%C3%AD)*).

Según el mismo diccionario, la etimología proviene del nahua *tlalcacahuatl*; de *tlalli*, tierra, y *cacahuatl*, cacao: cacao de tierra.

Por tanto, en un principio se podría pensar que la voz *cacahuate* es la más fiel al original. Y así parece ser porque el [Wikcionario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacahuatl) da como pronunciación IPA [ka.ˈka.wat͡ɬ], luego no parece haber confusión al respecto de esa última vocal.

Resulta muy esclarecedor que la palabra exista en muchos idiomas europeos con esa vocal intermedia convertida a *e*:

- Aragonés: cascagüet, calcagüet, cacagüet.
- Asturiano: cacagüés.
- Vasco: kakahuete.
- Catalán: cacauet.
- Francés: cacahuète.
- Luxemburgués: Kakuett.
- Gallego: cacahuete.

Esto hace pensar que la voz ya llegó a España con la vocal cambiada. Curiosas resultan las definiciones del diccionario de Terreros y Pando de 1786:

> CACAHUáTE, fruta de America, á modo de almendra, y mui ardiente.
>   CACAHUéTES, fruta de Indias, cuya planta sale de la tierra, y echa unas ramitas, que se doblan ácia bajo, y se encajan en la tierra misma, con ciertas vainas como espinas, dentro de las cuales está la fruta, que es sabrosa, y sana.

Igual lo que pasó es que en España se entendían ambas palabras con distintos significados. En el CORDE se encuentra, por supuesto, la palabra *cacahuate* en primer lugar:

> *Hay una moneda entre ellos con que venden y compran, que se llama cacahuate; es fruta de ciertos árboles muy preciados, de que hacen otro brebaje para grandes señores, que dicen ser cosa muy suavísima.*
>
> Alonso Zuazo, "Carta del licenciado Alonso Zuazo al padre Fray Luis de Figueroa, prior de la Mejorada", 1521 (México).

La siguiente aparición es en 1780, también en textos de México como *cacahuate*, y ya en la segunda mitad del siglo XIX aparece como *cacahuete*. No parece que fuera una palabra muy conocida hasta que los comerciantes europeos la introdujeron en Europa. De hecho, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cacahuate%2Ccacahuete&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccacahuate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcacahuate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCacahuate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCACAHUATE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccacahuete%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcacahuete%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCacahuete%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCACAHUETE%3B%2Cc0) solo tiene registros de ambas voces a partir de 1800 aproximadamente, y Corominas la cita como de uso a partir de la segunda mitad del siglo XVIII.

La variación a *[cacahuete](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacahuete)*, según el Wikcionario, se produjo por influencia de la palabra *[alcahuete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1anBlmj)*, presente en el español desde mucho antes de que la palabra *cacahuete* se hiciera popular (se encuentra en textos del siglo XII).

Comment: Ojo con esta aseveración: "_... mientras que la voz cacahuete es común en el resto del mundo hispanohablante._" Hay países en que se llama **maní** al fruto y probablemente a la planta también, y, no estoy totalmente seguro, pero en Chile creo haber oído **cacahuate**, a pesar de que este es uno de los países en donde se prefiere **maní**.

Comment: @AndrésChandía he modificado el párrafo para reflejar eso. Tienes razón, se me pasó el hecho de que en muchos países se prefiere la voz _maní_. Mis disculpas.